# local marked function variables unavailable inside trap function - (d)ash shell

Tags: linux, shell, posix, dash-shell

I've read that the `local` keyword introduces dynamic scoping, meaning the variable defined thus in a function will be visible until the function dies. Hence visible and changeable in other functions that this
function calls etc. However it seems that if there's a subshell inside a function (so the scope of the function will outlive the subshell), the local variable are, as expected, available inside the subshell normally, unless the trap function gets called. Inside the trap function, the variables defined as `local` in the outer (containing the subshell) function are unavailable. I tested in `bash` and don't see this problem, but I need to write `ash/dash` script and don't know if it's anything to
do with some sort of `POSIX` rule.

Can someone please explain why in the following example (in `ash`) `$a`
and `$b` error out in trap (due to `set -u`) while `$c` and `$d` work fine ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ash

f() {

     local a='This gives an error in g() below: "a: parameter not set"';

     local b='This gives an error in g() below: "b: parameter not set"';

     c='Works fine';

     (

     set -e;

     set -u;

     # even though it's defined again in subshell, it's still unavailable in trap function

     b='This gives an error in g() below: "b: parameter not set"';

     d='Works fine';

     g() {

         printf 'Trap\n';

         printf 'd=%s\n' "${d}"; #fine

         printf 'c=%s\n' "${c}"; #fine

         printf 'b=%s\n' "${b}"; #error

         printf 'a=%s\n' "${a}"; #error

     }

     trap g INT QUIT TERM HUP EXIT;

     )

}

f;
```

Comment: POSIX doesn't define locals at all (they're one of the few extensions that dash implements), so no behavior is defined by the standard -- thus, any and every behavior is allowed, including this one.

Comment: BTW, I strongly advise against `set -e`; its behavior is poorly defined, [varies wildly between shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) as well as between individual versions of shells, and is often [surprising even to folks who consider themselves experts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: Aha, I see. Thanks ! So I take it there's no equivalent of `local` to constrain the scope similarly in POSIX ?

Comment: Correct, POSIX sh has no equivalent to `local`.

Comment: @ustulation : Also, POSIX shell does not have nested functions, so the whole design concept is flawed.

Comment: I see. This was mostly for initcpio custom hooks in arch and it seems that's what some of the predefined hooks follow there. I thought it might be a standard practice.